# Uploading image with FastAPI cause exc.ResourceClosedError

Tags: python, fastapi

I have an endpoint which saves uploaded image to it:

```
@router.post("/v1/installation/{installation_uuid}/image")
@db.create_connection
async def upload_installation_image(installation_uuid: UUID, request: Request):
    content_type = request.headers["content-type"]
    async with db.transaction():
        installation = await get_installation_by_uuid(installation_uuid)
        if not installation:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"Installation {installation} not found")

        try:
            content = await request.body()
            image_uuid = await save_installation_image(installation.uuid, content, content_type)
        except Exception as e:
            log.debug(f"An error raised while uploading image: {e}")
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, detail="Error while uploading image to db"
            )

        return {"image_uuid": image_uuid}
```

`save_installation_image` make simple insert into DB.
In my tests I send 3 request to this endpoint. and all works fine:

**tests.py**

```
# upload image 1
        data1 = b"\x01\x02\x03\x61\x05\x61"
        response = session.post(
            f"/v1/installation/{installation_uuid}/image", data=data1, headers={"content-type": "image/png"}
        )
# upload image 2
        data2 = b"\x01\x02\x03\x61\x05\x62"
        response = session.post(
            f"/v1/installation/{installation_uuid}/image", data=data2, headers={"content-type": "image/png"}
        )
# upload image 3
        data3 = b"\x01\x02\x03\x61\x05\x63"
        response = session.post(
            f"/v1/installation/{installation_uuid}/image", data=data3, headers={"content-type": "image/png"}
        )
```

But when FE start calling that request, each request after first one start failing with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 404, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/message_logger.py", line 86, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/message_logger.py", line 82, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, inner_receive, inner_send)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 75, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 64, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 680, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 275, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 231, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 160, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/toolbox/asyncio_db.py", line 153, in wrapper
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/src/installation.py", line 347, in upload_installation_image
    installation = await get_installation_by_uuid(installation_uuid)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/src/installation.py", line 64, in get_installation_by_uuid
    row = (await db.execute(query, installation_uuid=str(installation_uuid))).fetchone()
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/toolbox/asyncio_db.py", line 116, in execute
    return await active_connection.execute(query, **params)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/toolbox/asyncio_db.py", line 50, in execute
    return await t.execute(query, **params)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/toolbox/asyncio_db.py", line 30, in execute
    return await self.async_connection.execute(text(query).bindparams(**params))
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py", line 453, in execute
    result = await greenlet_spawn(
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 115, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.switch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 333, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1572, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1798, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/opt/kelvatek/camlin-relink-broker/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 650, in _revalidate_connection
    raise exc.ResourceClosedError("This Connection is closed")
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed
```

Also, when I change by data to data which send FE, it start failing for me as well. What may cause this error, and why if I send real images connection close after first request?

**P.S.** If I send just 1 image, it works fine, so problem in sending several requests.

**UPDATES**

This is how I manage connection to db:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def connection(self):
    active_connection = self.get_active_connection()
    if active_connection:
        yield active_connection
        return

    async with self.engine.connect() as conn:
        try:
            wrapper = ConnectionWrapper(conn)
            token = self.active_connection.set(wrapper)
            await self.set_connection_options()
            if not self.collation_check_done:
                await self.check_collation()
                self.collation_check_done = True
            yield wrapper
        finally:
            self.active_connection.reset(token)

def create_connection(self, func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        async with self.connection():
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This is my Wrappers classes:

```
class TransactionWrapper:
    def __init__(self, async_connection, async_transaction):
        self.async_connection = async_connection
        self.async_transaction = async_transaction
        self.after_commit_callbacks = []

    def add_after_commit_callback(self, fn):
        self.after_commit_callbacks.append(fn)

    async def execute(self, query, **params):
        return await self.async_connection.execute(text(query).bindparams(**params))

    async def commit(self):
        await self.async_transaction.commit()
        while self.after_commit_callbacks:
            fn = self.after_commit_callbacks.pop(0)
            fn()

    async def rollback(self):
        await self.async_transaction.rollback()


class ConnectionWrapper:
    def __init__(self, async_connection):
        self.async_connection = async_connection
        self.active_transaction = contextvars.ContextVar('active_transaction')

    async def execute(self, query, **params):
        t = self.get_active_transaction()
        if t:
            return await t.execute(query, **params)

        # create temporary transaction in case it doesn't exists (simulates autocommit feature)
        async with self.transaction() as t:
            return await t.execute(query, **params)

    def get_active_transaction(self):
        try:
            return self.active_transaction.get()
        except LookupError:
            return None

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def transaction(self):
        # reuse existing transaction
        active_transaction = self.get_active_transaction()
        if active_transaction:
            yield active_transaction
            return

        async with self.async_connection.begin() as async_transaction:
            wrapper = TransactionWrapper(self.async_connection, async_transaction)
            token = self.active_transaction.set(wrapper)
            try:
                yield wrapper
            except Exception:
                await wrapper.rollback()
                raise
            else:
                await wrapper.commit()
            finally:
                self.active_transaction.reset(token)
```

Comment: This is showing that your database connection was closed, isn't it?

Comment: @TimRoberts, yes it is, but why its happened? If I send 1 request, it works fine, all db queries works fine, but second and later request failing with that error. Also if I will use small bytes data instead of big image bytes data which FE sends, it will works fine.

Comment: Well, are you closing the connection?  Are you, perhaps, opening it in a `with` statement and then exiting the `with`?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I have add some additional code where I manage the connection.

Comment: Yeah, but that code is wrong.  You can't use a `with` statement with an object that needs a longer lifetime.  You `yield` the connection, but as soon as the yield finishes, you'll exit the `with` statement, and the connection will be closed.  `with` is specifically intended for objects with a limited lifetime -- they live as long as the `with` lives.  I think you need to scrap the `with` and just do a normal assignment.